# Sending data securely in a POST to a REST API

Tags: api, rest, security

I would like to send some "private" data on a POST request. This data is placed in the body and sent over TLS so it is encrypted.

Additionally to the TLS encryption is there any other mechanism that should by applied to protect that data?

Update

In order to have not only transport layer encryption but application layer encryption to guarantee confidentiality, as NinjaSecurity suggested currently I client encrypts with a private key and server decrypts with the public key. This mechanism requires key exchange between server and client side and clients must be able to perform asymetric encription which may be a bit painful depending on the language used in the client side. The question is: Transport layer encryption is enough to assure confidentiality or data could be compromised from transport layer to application layer?

Thanks,
Ivan.

Comment: What's your threat model? Who are you protecting that data from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all honesty, you don't really need another layer over TLS/SSL. The security of SSL is well-established for secured certificates, and it's a worldwide standard for a reason. Securing the transport layer is sufficient for foiling an eavesdropper, and any attacker who has sufficient access to either the client or the server to compromise TLS would certainly be able to retrieve the keys being used by any application-layer encryption. In addition, you wouldn't be able to provide secure crypto code to your client (I.e. JavaScript) without an existing secure connection; if you can't trust TLS, how can your client trust the code you supply? And how can you establish a secure connection with your client's browser without giving them code to run?

Answer (score 0):

what you want to achieve by adding additional security layer , confidentiality or integrity? if you assume that TLS is compromised then your server must be compromised and so any additional layer of control i.e. additional encryption wont help either. Also it will impact your application performance .

Comment: confidentiality. The goal is to have encryption in the application layer not only in the transport layer.

Comment: i thought so ...then best way is to add client side encryption using public key and decrypt at server side using private key. long time back stanford university has released crypto libraries, I have never used it but you can try  https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/..

Comment: Thanks Ninja, currently is what I am using but it requires key exchange between server and client side and clients must be able to perform asymetric encription which may be a bit painful depending on the language used in the client side. The question is: Transport layer encryption is enough or data could be compromised from transport layer to application layer. (I will update my question to post that)